# Mocking Angular $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mocking

Could anybody suggest me a way how to mock `$resource` object

I've searched though internet, but all my tries were finished by KARMA testing.
I don't need it.

My idea is to have just fake object, so I will be able to switch between `$resource` implementations in my app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$provide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/object/%24provide) to do this.

```
angular.module(“MyApp”,[])

.config([“$provide”,function($provide){

  $provide.decorator(“$resource”,function($delegate, myReplacementResource){
        //$delegate is the original $resource, if you just want to modify it    

        //either inject a replacement resource that you have already registered
        //as a factory (recommended).  Or make it here.

        return myReplacementResource;

    });

}])
```

Answer (score 1):

dskh presented one way to do it. Here's a another way which you might find to be easier... although it's ofen used for unit testing, you can use [angular-mocks.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js) in your app as well:

```
app.run(function($httpBackend) {

  $httpBackend.whenPOST('/string/match/url').respond(function (method, url, data) {
    return [{some:data}];
  });

  $httpBackend.whenGET(/regexpmatch/).respond(function (method, url, data) {
    return {some:{other:data}};
  });

  // pass through other stuff
  $httpBackend.whenPOST(/.*/).passThrough();
  $httpBackend.whenGET(/.*/).passThrough();
  $httpBackend.whenDELETE(/.*/).passThrough();
  $httpBackend.whenJSONP(/.*/).passThrough();
  $httpBackend.whenPUT(/.*/).passThrough();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/5cVuRfXaLhxa1h53Lf3j?p=info) shows how I go about mocking resource objects, from a angular service, in a controller. I use [SinonJs](http://sinonjs.org/) to fake a resource object. Then I basically fake the promise chain by injecting $q.

To fake the promise chain you need to get a defer object from $q, then get a promise from it.

In your tests, you then either fake a success or a failure by calling `promise.resolve()` or `promise.reject()` on that promise. You can fake data from the server by passing an object in as a parameter like this `promise.reject(someData)`.

You then have to make sure that you `scope.apply()`. To make sure that whatever it is you wanted to do becomes visible on scope.

I'm not entirely sure if this is the right way to go about this, but it has been working for me.