# AngularJS : Testing factory that returns $http promises

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-promise

Trying to test an angular service that returns an `$http` GET request and the `then` handler, but I'm not able to test that the logic actually works inside of the `then` function. Here is a basic, truncated version of the service code:

```
angular.module('app').factory('User', function ($http) {
  var User = {};

  User.get = function(id) {
    return $http.get('/api/users/' + id).then(function (response) {
      var user = response.data;
      user.customProperty = true;  
      return user;
    });
  };

  return User;
});
```

And here is the test:

```
beforeEach(module('app'));
beforeEach(inject(function(_User_, _$q_, _$httpBackend_, _$rootScope_) {
  $q = _$q_;
  User = _User_;
  $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
  $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
}));

afterEach(function () {
  $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
});

describe('User factory', function () {

  it('gets a user and updates customProperty', function () {
    $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/users/123').respond({ id: 123 });
    User.get(123).then(function (user) {
      expect(user.customProperty).toBe(true);  // this never runs
    });

    $httpBackend.flush();
  });

});
```

I feel like I've tried pretty much everything to test the logic in the `then` call, so if someone can offer suggestions I would greatly appreciate it.

Edit: my problem was also due to nonstandard injection practices, so the answer below worked outside of that.

Comment: If you are doing this in a service, then you wouldn't have scope to apply. So, I always put the promise chain stuff in my controllers and test it there. Here is a link to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/24407839/2740086

Comment: Thanks for that. Yeah I am able to pass in a fake promise when I test the use of the factory in, say, a controller, but I want to test that the logic inside of the factory promise is sound. Is that just bad practice?

Comment: What I do is this: I separate the promise stuff in the controller, so I can control it with promise.resolve() then $scope.apply(). I then pass a success or failure object to a "resolver" service that actually does what I want with that success or failure. Basically the service has a getResourceFromServer() method and a resolveGetResourceFromServer(objectFromServer, successBool) method that I use to do whatever in the service. I don't know if it is "best practice" but I find it makes testing a little easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things need to be changed

- Use `whenGET` instead of `expectGET` in order to fake a response
- In the test `then` callback, set the response to a variable available outside the callback so you can test it in an `expect` call
- Make sure the `expect` call is outside any callbacks, so it always runs and shows any failures.

Putting it all together:

```
it('gets a user and updates customProperty', function () {
  $httpBackend.whenGET('/api/users/123').respond({ id: 123 });
  User.get(123).then(function(response) {
    user = response;
  })
  $httpBackend.flush();
  expect(user.customProperty).toBe(true); 
});
```

As can be seen at http://plnkr.co/edit/9zON7ALKnrKpcOVrBupQ?p=preview

Comment: You can also use the jasmine spyOn and andCallFake tools, to return a promise with the state you want, but, in order to do that, you must have to separate the loading business into a dedicated service. A service can be mocked, and then the spyOn become usable.
If you want to mock the $http without using the $httpBackend, you can mock it throught a module(function($provide) { $provide.value('$http', yourBadMockBecauseYouAreLazy ); })

Comment: Could it have something to do with how we're injecting $http then? Because I still get "No pending requests to flush" when I try that.

We call it like `var $http = angular.injector(['dn']).get('$http');` to have our resources extend a base Resource type.

Comment: @Tom It sounds like the code you posted might not be representative of your actual situation. As there is now an answer to this question (i.e. mine!) I suggest posting a new question with code that shows your issue, with a link to a Plunker showing it work (or rather, not work).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion with all this, your fix did work once I changed how the service was defined. Has to do with the `$injector` possibly returning a new instance of `$http`, but that needs a separate investigation.