# AngularJS & Karma-Jasmin - Not all tests are executed, only the first one

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I want to test my code using Karma-Jasmin, but when I run the tests only the first one gets fired. I found out that it works when I delete some parts of code, I'll paste it on the bottom.

This is my whole Jasmine code

```
describe("UserHandler", function(){
    var el, scope, controller, configServiceSpy, myService, userDetails, myController, $httpBackend;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('agenda');

        beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_){
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        }));

        inject(function (userHandler) {
            myService = userHandler;

            myService.userDetails = {};
            myService.userId = "P123";
            myService.userDetails.expire_timestamp = 999999999999;
            $httpBackend.expectGET('http://..../123').respond(200, {"foo" : "bar", "foo2": "bar2", "address": { "street":"some street" }})

            myService.requestUserDetails();
            userDetails = myService.userDetails;

        });

        inject(function($compile, $rootScope){
            el = angular.element("<login-sidebar></login-sidebar>");
            $compile(el)($rootScope.$new());
                $rootScope.$digest();
                scope = el.isolateScope() || el.scope() ;
        }); 
    });

    afterEach(function(){
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    it("true is true", function(){
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });

    it("requestUserDetails", function(){
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(Object.keys(myService.userDetails).length).toBeGreaterThan(0);

    });

    it("getUserStreet not null", function(){
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(myService.userDetails.address.street).not.toBeNull();
    });

    xit("getUserStreet null", function(){
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(myService.userDetails.address.street).toBeNull();
    });

});
```

This is the output in the console

```
Chrome 43.0.2357 (Mac OS X 10.10.3): Executed 1 of 4 (skipped 1) SUCCESS (0.079 secs / 0.07 secs)
```

So when I delete the parts that do something with HTTP request it works

It works when I delete these lines of code

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_){
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
}));

inject(function (userHandler) {
    myService = userHandler;

    myService.userDetails = {};
    myService.userId = "P123";
    myService.userDetails.expire_timestamp = 999999999999;
    $httpBackend.expectGET('http://..../123').respond(200, {"foo" : "bar", "foo2": "bar2", "address": { "street":"some street" }})

    myService.requestUserDetails();
    userDetails = myService.userDetails;

});

afterEach(function(){
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});
```

What am I doing wrong ? Why is it not executing all test only the first one (it doesn't matter which one of the tests is the first one).

Comment: why a beforeEach inside another and multiple inject? see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing for a code example

Comment: possible duplicate of [Testing factory that returns $http promises](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126372/testing-factory-that-returns-http-promises)